# Get list of folders from assets folder

Tags: android, android-assets

I'm trying to load files from assets folder. Assets folder contains two folders dir1, dir2 and file file1. I'm using following code:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();

String[] data = null;
try {
    data = am.list("");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This gives me following output: `sounds, images, webkit, file1`. Anyone knows how to list folders dir1, dir2?

P.S. If I do `data = am.list("dir1");` it shows me files, that located in dir1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is appeared that folders were empty, and method `AssetManager.list("");` doesn't return empty folders.

Comment: That is because those folders do not exist. This is standard ZIP archive behavior, where "folders" are only designated as paths on files in the archive.